# How to display the tables side by side using thymleaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

[image]    private int accno;
    private List reasons;

want to display first one(accno & reasons) left side and second  right side, third left and fourth right side....

sample code is not working

```
<table>
<tr th:each="cust: ${customer}">
    <td th:text="${cust.accno}" />
    <td th:text="${cust.reasons}" />
</tr>
</table>
```

Expected output attached screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I dont have IDE now, but I hope my code can help you:

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="cust, iter: ${customer}" th:if="${iter.even}" >
        <td th:text="${cust[iter.index].accno}" />
        <td th:text="${cust[iter.index].reasons}" />
        <td th:text="${cust[iter.index+1].accno}" />
        <td th:text="${cust[iter.index+1].reasons}" />
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: If my solution helped you, could you acept my answer? This will help others know which solution works for your problem

Comment: could you please send me approve link